# OsmDroid make on cluster clicklistener

Tags: kotlin, osmdroid

I have a clustered markers working in Kotlin project, but now is possibility to have on one clustered marker for example two points with the same coordinates. Now I need to have in this case listener or there are differen coordinates or the same and react on this.

IS there a possibility to make cluster marker listener? I need to zoom to marker wjen clustered points are the same. How to make it?